# Move-Item not reading the path correctly

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I have this script where i want to move files from one path to another:

```
$logArchieveDirectory='C:\LogArchieve\'+$archiveTillDate.Day+$archiveTillDate.Month+$archiveTillDate.Year;
$sourcePathServer = 'C:\DDS\Server\LOGS';
$destPathServer=$logArchieveDirectory+'\Server';

#Create Directories
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $logArchieveDirectory;
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $destPathServer;

#Moving Logs to new temporary log archieve directories
foreach( $item in (Get-ChildItem $sourcePathServer | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -le $archiveTillDate }) )
{
    Move-Item $item $destPathServer -force;
}
```

However, i have specified both paths fine But i keep getting this error when i run this script.

```
Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\DDS\WorkFolder\WebAdapter' because it does not exist.
At C:\DDS\WorkFolder\powerShellScript08062014.ps1:38 char:11
+     Move-Item <<<<  $item $destPathController;
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\DDS\WorkFolder\WebAdapter:String) [Move-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

The `C:\DDS\WorkFolder\` is actually the folder where my script file is located. But what i am not understanding is why it is looking for the folder here and not where the path is given i.e. `$sourcePathServer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script passes relative paths to Move-Item and it defaults to the working directory. An easy solution is to pass absolute paths using `.FullName` property:

```
foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem $sourcePathServer `
| Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -le $archiveTillDate })) {
    Move-Item $item.FullName $destPathServer -force
}
```

Also using `foreach` in conjunction with pipelines doesn't look very elegant because of all the parentheses. You can get rid of it:

```
Get-ChildItem $sourcePathServer `
| Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -le $archiveTillDate } | Foreach-Object {
    Move-Item $_.FullName $destPathServer -Force
}
```

Comment: full paths? I am not currently using the full path like `C:\DDS\Server\LOGS` ?

Comment: You do, but only when you search for items with Get-ChildItem. I edited my answer for more clarity.